# How to work out how many Folder are in a folder vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, directory

I want to be able to would out how many folders there are in a folder. This is because i was to make a back up system and i want to be able to say if there is already 5 folders in the folder then delete the oldest and add the new one in. How would i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked it out,

```
Dim counter As  _
System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection(Of String)
        counter = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories("C:\test")
        MsgBox("number of folders is " & CStr(counter.Count))
```

I just got the file one and modified it a bit :).... Now to work out the date system

Answer (score 2):

To start with, you can get a collection of all the subdirectories using the [My.Computer.FileSystem.GetDirectories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w84x2t4z%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) method. It should be trivial to find out how many items exist in that collection.

If you need to search for the oldest one then use the [My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/6bz6zd00%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) method on each of the items from the previous API call. The returned FileInfo object will contain the creation time amongst other information. Hope this helps!